# Os.system() - Changing zip command to give a different file name for various datetimes

Tags: python, zip, os.system

I am trying to zip a directory with a date-time stamp added to the created zip folder. How would I go about doing this? I have tried something like this:

```
import datetime   
import os
backup_zip = True
    if backup_zip:
        dt = ('{:%Y%m%d_%H%M}'.format(datetime.datetime.now()))
        name = dt + "folder.zip"
        os.system("zip -r" + name +  "/home/olb/CPL")
```

This works, but without the date-time stamp:

```
# os.system("zip -r folder.zip /home/olb/CPL")
```

Many thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure there are spaces around the name.

With your current implementation, the argument being provided to `os.system()` is:

```
zip -r<name>/home/olb/CPL
```

When instead it should be:

```
zip -r <name> /home/olb/CPL
```

The simplest fix is adding a space before the preceding quote and a space after the following quote:

```
os.system("zip -r " + name +  " /home/olb/CPL")
```

---

If you're using Python 3.6+, you can use [formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals):

```
name = f"{dt}folder.zip"
command = f"zip -r {name} /home/olb/CPL"
```

This can be easier to deal with versus dealing with quotes and concatenation using `+`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to properly format [command line command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Anatomy_of_a_shell_CLI) like this:

```
import datetime
import os

backup_zip = True
if backup_zip:
    dt = '{:%Y%m%d_%H%M}'.format(datetime.datetime.now())
    name = dt + "folder.zip"
    os.system("zip -r " + name +  " /home/olb/CPL")
```